# JBoss DataVirt -- 6.4 -- connection support to MapRDB?

Tags: redhat-datavirt

Is there support available or forthcoming to use MapRDB as a datasource for JBoss DataVirt?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but Teiid has extensible API that one can use write new translators. I encourage you to add a JIRA to log the request.